# How did my answer become a community wiki?

Tags: support

I posted an answer to this question [Does the theology of Arians and Jehovah's Witnesses admit that God was at one point ἄλογος?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11974/does-the-theology-of-arians-and-jehovahs-witnesses-admit-that-god-was-at-one-po) a few minutes ago, and I see now it says it has been made into a commmunity wiki?  How did that happen?  Did I click some obscure checkbox or something?   Is it because the question is old?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an obscure checkbox you might have checked (bottom right):

[image: Answer box]

You might have checked it accidently either initially or while editing.

But in any case, I've removed the wiki status. Enjoy!

Comment: Isn't there also an edit limit before it is made a community wiki? Like 10 eidts and it is made one?

Comment: [Not any more.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/)